# MongoDB index on nullable array not being used

Tags: arrays, mongodb, optimization, indexing, mongodb-query

I have a document like this:

```
{
  "field1:"value1",
  "list1" : [{field1:"value2"}, ...]
}
```

and list1 can be null. My index is:

```
{"field1":1, "_id":1, "list1":1}
```

The query

```
.find({"field1":"value1"}, {"field1":1, "_id":1})
```

is using the index and it's returning **PROJECTION_COVERED** in the exec stats.

But

```
.find({"field1":"value1"}, {"field1":1, "_id":1, "list1":1})
```

is **FETCH**ing after IXSCAN, which is taking a lot of time.

I need the list1 not to be sparse. I need the query to return valued and null values for list1. Is there anything I can do to optimize the query?

Comment: I also tried indexing list1.field1, with no success

Comment: What is the selectivity of those fields? , and how big is the list1 field?  , at first look it seems more effective to have {"field1":1,_id:1} indexed only ...

Comment: field1, as well as list1.field1, are simple strings. Both CAN be low-selectivty, cause there can be little to many of value1 and value2 in the other docs. But list1.field1 has more null values (missing field) than valued. Actually, it's list1 which can missing at all. I saw that mongo does not use the index for lists, in general, both if I index the entire list (list1) or its nested doc (list1.field1). Why is it not able to use index with list1.field1 if I project it ? I know that Mongo indexes nulls